# Why is intersect(...) faster than data table join?

Tags: r, data.table

This question was prompted by [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307020/).

Consider two vectors, `a` and `b`, and two data tables `dt.a` and `dt.b` as follows:

```
a <- c(55, 1:25)
b <- c(55,30:40)

library(data.table)
dt.a <- data.table(x=a,key="x")
dt.b <- data.table(x=b,key="x")

intersect(a,b)
[1] 55
dt.a[dt.b,nomatch=0]
    x
1: 55
```

The objective is to count the number of common elements.

**My question** is: why is data table join 30X slower than `intersect(...)`

```
system.time(for (i in 1:1000){intersect(a,b)})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.04 
system.time(for (i in 1:1000){dt.a[dt.b,nomatch=0]})
   user  system elapsed 
   1.68    0.00    1.69
```

Comment: For small data, the overhead due to `[.data.table` might be a dominating factor. Try it on bigger data. Also, `joins` are designed with more than 1 column in mind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The power of data.table shines when given a "big" problem. The overheads of `[.data.table` will dwarf the time actually spend on the binary search component.

If you give it a "big" problem, then `data.table` will scale and you will see the difference.

```
# a "bigger" problem
a <- c(55, 1:25e6)
b <- c(55,30:40e6)

library(data.table)
dt.a <- data.table(x=a,key="x")
dt.b <- data.table(x=b,key="x")

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(intersect(a,b), dt.a[dt.b, nomatch=0],times=5)
## Unit: seconds
##                     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
##          intersect(a, b) 6.848245 6.897009 6.962055 7.052095 7.058509     5
##  dt.a[dt.b, nomatch = 0] 3.629062 3.654269 3.685051 3.721983 3.815155     5
```

Comment: Thanks! So the answer seems to be that the overhead for `[data.table` is quite substantial. When I rerun your benchmark for vectors of length O(25,000), `intersect(...)` still wins!

Comment: @jlhoward -25000 is not particularly large. `[.data.table` has the overhead of the function itself as well as the overhead associated with s3 method dispatch in R. I would suggest it is the latter which is contributing the most.